# Como forzar https con htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Estimados estoy intentando forzar el certificado SSL con https, pero estoy teniendo inconvenientes

Si en mi navegador escribo **http://ecuservicechile.cl** o **ecuservicechile.cl** si soy redireccionado a **https://ecuservicechile.cl/**, pero si escribo **[www.ecuservicechile.cl](http://www.ecuservicechile.cl)** soy redireccionado a **https://www.ecuservicechile.cl/** con  lo cual tengo problema con los estilos y con los demás elementos como imágenes o iconos.

Como puedo forzar correctamente el https para que funcione en los 3 casos, estoy usando las siguientes reglas en htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ecuservicechile.cl/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

Answer (score 3):

si entendí bien tu sitio funciona bien en el dominio sin www, lo que puedes hacer es forzar que si escriben el dominio con www los lleve a la versión sin www, todo completo sería algo así:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ecuservicechile.cl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ecuservicechile.cl/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```